# Qlikview - sum in script

Tags: qlikview

i have script

```
LOAD * INLINE [
 Document, Date, Itam, Line, Saldo, Unit
 Doc1, 12.12.2015, Item1, 1, 10, m
 Doc1, 3.04.2015, Item2, 2, 15, kg
 Doc2, 11.09.2015, Item1, 1, 6, kg
 Doc3, 11.04.2015, Item1, 1, 13, m
 Doc3, 21.03.2015, Item5, 2, 45, l
 Doc4, 20.04.2016, Item4, 1, 7, l
 Doc5, 12.01.2016, Item1, 1, 13, kg
 Doc6, 7.09.2016, Item3, 1, 16, m
 Doc6, 21.09.2016, Item3, 2, 21, kg
 Doc7, 1.01.2016, Item2, 1, 3, l
];
```

I want to get sum of Saldo by year in script. How can I modify script to get something like this:

```
Load
Year2015,
SumOfSaldo2015,
Year2016,
SumOfSaldo2016
```

And when I call SumOfSaldo2015 in text box to get sum of saldo for year 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a slightly strange thing to do when you should be able to achieve it via using dimensions in QlikView - just create a year Dimension based on the date...

```
LOAD *,
 right(Date,4) as Year;
LOAD * INLINE [
 Document, Date, Itam, Line, Saldo, Unit
 Doc1, 12.12.2015, Item1, 1, 10, m
 Doc1, 3.04.2015, Item2, 2, 15, kg
 Doc2, 11.09.2015, Item1, 1, 6, kg
 Doc3, 11.04.2015, Item1, 1, 13, m
 Doc3, 21.03.2015, Item5, 2, 45, l
 Doc4, 20.04.2016, Item4, 1, 7, l
 Doc5, 12.01.2016, Item1, 1, 13, kg
 Doc6, 7.09.2016, Item3, 1, 16, m
 Doc6, 21.09.2016, Item3, 2, 21, kg
 Doc7, 1.01.2016, Item2, 1, 3, l
];
```

Or if you're after just a consolidated view...

```
Temp:
LOAD *,
 right(Date,4) as Year;
LOAD * INLINE [
 Document, Date, Itam, Line, Saldo, Unit
 Doc1, 12.12.2015, Item1, 1, 10, m
 Doc1, 3.04.2015, Item2, 2, 15, kg
 Doc2, 11.09.2015, Item1, 1, 6, kg
 Doc3, 11.04.2015, Item1, 1, 13, m
 Doc3, 21.03.2015, Item5, 2, 45, l
 Doc4, 20.04.2016, Item4, 1, 7, l
 Doc5, 12.01.2016, Item1, 1, 13, kg
 Doc6, 7.09.2016, Item3, 1, 16, m
 Doc6, 21.09.2016, Item3, 2, 21, kg
 Doc7, 1.01.2016, Item2, 1, 3, l
];

Saldo:
LOAD 
 Year AS Year,
 sum(Saldo) as SumOfSaldo
RESIDENT TEMP
GROUP BY Year;
```

However if you really needed to do it, you could do something like...

```
Temp:
LOAD *,
 right(Date,4) as Year;
LOAD * INLINE [
 Document, Date, Itam, Line, Saldo, Unit
 Doc1, 12.12.2015, Item1, 1, 10, m
 Doc1, 3.04.2015, Item2, 2, 15, kg
 Doc2, 11.09.2015, Item1, 1, 6, kg
 Doc3, 11.04.2015, Item1, 1, 13, m
 Doc3, 21.03.2015, Item5, 2, 45, l
 Doc4, 20.04.2016, Item4, 1, 7, l
 Doc5, 12.01.2016, Item1, 1, 13, kg
 Doc6, 7.09.2016, Item3, 1, 16, m
 Doc6, 21.09.2016, Item3, 2, 21, kg
 Doc7, 1.01.2016, Item2, 1, 3, l
];

Saldo:
LOAD 
 Year AS Year2015,
 sum(Saldo) as SumOfSaldo2015
RESIDENT TEMP
GROUP BY Year
WHERE Year = 2015;

CONCATENATE(Saldo)
LOAD 
 Year AS Year2016,
 sum(Saldo) as SumOfSaldo2016
RESIDENT TEMP
GROUP BY Year
WHERE Year = 2016;

DROP TABLE Temp;
```